# refresh multiple iframes based on a variable "id" from one button

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, refresh

I have a php page that has multiple iframes on the page.

these iframes contain a button if you will.  When someone clicks on the "button" im firing javascript to refresh another frame on the page with id=xxx this works fine.  the problem is i want to be able to refresh multiple frames on the page they all cant have the same ID value so How could this be done.

```
<iframe id="12345"></iframe>
<iframe id="12345"></iframe>
<iframe id="12345"></iframe>
```

This works on a single iframe (i know you cant have multiple ids the same on one document.) The idea is want to do something like this.

```
parent.document.getElementById('12345').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Sorry for the sloppy example, ive been awake far to long. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using at it works great! I made the iframe as follows:

```
<iframe name="ifwXXXX"></iframe>
```

Then I was able to use the below code to get all the iframes that had the same name and loop through them refreshing each.

```
function refreshwant(ifid,lid){
    parent.document.getElementById('pfid'+lid+'').contentWindow.location.reload();
    var x = parent.document.getElementsByName('ifw'+ifid+'');
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    x[i].contentWindow.location.reload();    
}
}
```

Thanks for all the help hope this can help someone as well.!

Answer (score 3):

Just assign different ids and call

```
parent.document.getElementById(customId).contentWindow.location.reload();
```

multiple times, once each for every iFrame you want to reload.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices, either iterate over all the id's reloading each as needed...

Or if you are reloading **ALL** frames, you can use this:

```
for(var i=0;i<window.frames.length;i++){
  window.frames[i].location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* include in parent */
function reloadIframes( ) {
    var i = argument.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        document.getElementById( arguments[i] ).contentWindow.location.reload()
    }
}
/* In an iframe (probably in the onclick of your button) */
parent.reloadIframes( 'id1', 'id2' );
```